# The big log file.What this?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a lot of kern.log file. And size of 10GB+

but, in file text all to

```
AMD-Vi : Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=01:00.0 domain=0x0014 address=0x0000000000001000 flags=0x0000]
```

Note : device=01:00.0

lspci

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G92 [GeForce 9800 GT] (rev a2)
```

A few days ago I upgrade to CPU(FX8300) and Graphics card(9800GT).
Graphics drivers use of NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.65.
my uname -a

```
Linux timepower 3.18.1-031801-generic #201412170637 SMP Wed Dec 17 11:38:50 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Sorry, My english is bad ;-)

this is my lshw

http://paste.ubuntu.com/9633122/

Comment: Where exactly is this file located? `/var/log`?

Comment: @Daniel B yes, /var/log/kern.log && /var/log/nvidia-installer.log

Comment: Ok. You mention VirtualBox. How is it related? Which Linux distribution are you using? Ubuntu?

Comment: @@Daniel B Thx, The virtualbox IO of AMD-Vi(IOMMU) support, i use xubuntu 14.04;-)